# Как переустановить винду

Tags: windows-7, setup

Помогите ламеру.Нужно переустановить винду из флешки,БЕЗ ПОТЕРИ ДАННЫХ.
P.s.только через биос.

Comment: В следующий раз делайте отдельный раздел для данных...

Comment: Пробовали сначала гуглить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите переустановить Windows без потери данных, то их стоит перенести на диски (жесткие диски, флешки и т.п.). Так же вам нужно иметь как минимум 2 жестких диска, чтобы потом было проще переустанавливать.

И так. Для начала вам нужно скачать ISO-образ нужной версии Windows и записать его на флешку с использованием программы, например, ultraiso. Далее вы перезагружаете компьютер с вставленной в него флешкой и загружаетесь с нее (приоритет загрузки можно выставить в БИОСе). Ну а далее все делаете по инструкции на экране.

Так же хочу скачать, что Windows нужно хранить на отдельном жестком диске, лучше на SSD, чтобы все остальные файлы и программы хранились отдельно. Так вы не потеряете нужные файлы, если будете переустанавливать систему.

Comment: Возможности перенести данные нет.ПК не вкл. полностью.

Comment: @CraftPE если ПК не включается, то как вы хотите переустановить ОС? Или вы имеете в виду, что не можете загрузить Windows?

Comment: @CraftPE если вы не можете просто загрузить Windows, то запишите на болванку или на флешку дистрибутив Ubuntu или Linux Mint, загрузитесь с них (это можно сделать без их установки) и скопируйте все нужные файлы на диск.

Answer (score 2):

Это не то место, где задают такие вопросы. Вам бы в гугл/яндекс/бинг за поиском.
Но раз я уже начал

1) загрузите линукс из флешки, скопируйте необходимые данные и установите Windows

2) установите Windows без форматирования, старые файлы сможете достать в каталоге Windows.old

Это основные способы, не требующие больших знаний от пользователя. За подробностями извольте в поисковые системы. Инструкций много, сотни их. Когда будет вопрос потяжелее - обращайтесь.